# How to show a jquery message after textbox in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a textbox to show date which follows icon of jquery calandar to choose date. I used jquery form validation to show message if the user doesn't select a date. if i enter submit means that message shows between textbox and icon. I want that message after that icon. How to show that message?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague if you ask me! You should give use some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to reposition the validation message box with CSS, you should look up the API for this and find out which classes determin the CSS layout.

you can also have a look at the jQuery generated code with FireBug.